# How to fix the error that occurs when working with iron fish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, blockchain

I am building my own web platform on nodejs and am now in the server creation phase. I read the iron fish documentation and wrote this code, but I keep getting an error:
`RpcConnectionRefusedError`
I can't figure out how to bring up my own network or connect to someone else's network.

Here is my actual code where I tried to do the connection and networking.

````
import { IronfishSdk } from '@ironfish/sdk';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

async function connectWithRetry(sdk) {
    let isConnected = false;
    while (!isConnected) {
      try {
        await sdk.client.connect();
        isConnected = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        console.error('Connection failed. Retrying in 5 seconds...');
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
      }
    }
  }
  
  app.post('/createAccount', async (req, res) => {
      try {
          const sdk = await IronfishSdk.init({ network: 'myNetwork' });
          await connectWithRetry(sdk);
          const account = await sdk.client.wallet.createAccount({ name: 'accountName' });
          const response = {
              mnemonic: account.mnemonic.join(' '),
              address: account.defaultAddress,
          };
          res.json(response);
      } catch (error) {
          res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
      }
  });
  

app.post('/sendToken', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { mnemonic, toAddress, amount } = req.body;
        const sdk = await IronfishSdk.init({ network: 'myNetwork' });
        await sdk.client.connect();
        const account = await sdk.client.wallet.importAccount(mnemonic);
        const result = await sdk.client.sendTransaction(account, toAddress, amount);
        const response = {
            status: result.status,
            transaction: result.transaction,
        };
        res.json(response);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});```
````

Comment: You can check firewall settings for running remote server and check port number because of default port for Iron Fish RPC is often http port is 3030